# Execute stored function with PHP PDO

Tags: php, sql-server, pdo

I have this function stored on my SQL SERVER DATABASE

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fn_md5] (@data VARCHAR(10), @data2 VARCHAR(10))
RETURNS BINARY(16) AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @hash BINARY(16)
EXEC master.dbo.XP_MD5_EncodeKeyVal @data, @data2, @hash OUT
RETURN @hash
END
```

To get value that i need i some how to execute like this: `[dbo].[fn_md5]('data1','data2')`
How i do this in php with pdo?

If i use

```
$exc_line = $db->prepare("exec [dbo].[fn_md5]('data1','data2')");
$exc_line->execute();
$exc_line_data = $exc_line->fetch();
```

I get no results...

Comment: Why not `SELECT [dbo].[fn_md5]('data1','data2')` ?

Comment: @HAL9000 Thanks, this worked! i tough i need to exec or call it somehow.

Comment: Stored functions executing by `SELECT` statement. Stored procedures - by `EXEC` statement. Just saying.

Answer (score 3):

<sub>To resolve an issue, lets just compile the answer.</sub>

Stored functions executing by `SELECT` statement. Stored procedures - by `EXEC` statement, according to [**docs**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186755.aspx).

So use this:

```
SELECT [dbo].[fn_md5]('data1','data2')
```